# Is reading an index from a file a buffer overflow vulnerability?

Tags: c++, security, buffer-overflow

I recently used a static analysis tool (Checkmarx) to scan the source code of an old game engine to see if there are any buffer overflow vulnerabilities in it. I was surprised to see that the following code was flagged as a possible source of buffer overflows:

```cpp
// Get a pointer to a file that describes a 3D model
std::string filename = "my_3D_model.obj"
FILE* stream;
fopen_s(&stream, filename.c_str(), "rb");

// Read the number of vertices that make up the 3D model
int numVertices = 0;
fread(&numVertices, sizeof(int), 1, stream);

// Read the vertices and store them in a vector
// The static analysis tool doesn't complain about the use of numVertices to
// reserve space and to read from the file
std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
vertices.reserve(numVertices);
fread(vertices.data(), sizeof(Vertex), numVertices, stream);

// ...

// Copy the vertices from the vector to an array that has been allocated on the heap
// The static analysis tool complains because numVertices, which was read from a file,
// is being used as an index
Vertex* meshVertices = new Vertex[numVertices];
for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
{
    meshVertices[i] = vertices[i];
}
```

The static analysis tool calls this an "Index from input buffer overflow vulnerability". It sees that `int i` is ranging from 0 to `numVertices`, which was read from a file, and it thinks that that might cause a buffer overflow. But is it really possible in this particular case? `numVertices` is being used to allocate the size of the buffers, so I don't see how a buffer overflow could occur. And if it is possible, how would you prevent it? Note that I can't change the types of the buffers because that would break too much code.

Thanks for any information!

Comment: This looks like a false positive to me.  I think the analyzer is just seeing "read input from file" -> "used as index".  Maybe it does not recognize that it is also being used to allocate.  What happens if you std::vector<Vertex> vertices(numVertices); ?

Comment: Nup, my bad.  std::vector::reserve does NOT change the size of the vector.  It just allocates memory.  It should either init it with numVertices or resize(numVertices) the vector.  You can check this by checking the size() of the vector before the loop that grabs the values.

Comment: It's a signed `int`. What if the number is negative?

Comment: Why would you copy from a `std::vector` to "an array that has been allocated on the heap"? The vector is already that. Just pass it around with move semantics or copy elision construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is absolutely correct. You're reading a signed `int` from an external source and then promoting it to a `size_t` when you call `reserve` and `fread`. Since `size_t` is an unsigned type, if the value you read from the file is a negative number the resulting value when promoted to `size_t` is going to be much larger than the absolute value of `numVertices` on most platforms. The result is you're going to try to reserve and read a huge number of vectors. If those two operations succeed, you're then going to try to `new` a negative array size. Your `for` loop is guaranteed never to execute if you get that far.

The fix is to read the value as an unsigned int, or better yet a `size_t`, although that will require you to alter the code that writes the value. Another option is to at least validate the value. Trusting data from external sources is a great way to become this week's exploit.